# Exporting a Menu in Drupal

Tags: drupal

I'm new to Drupal. I created a menu that I placed inside the Sidebar First Region.

I was able to place my menu in the Sidebar First Region by going to the blocks page "admin/structure/block". Is a menu seen as a block, since I am able to assign a region for a menu inside the BLOCKS page? or is just the name of the page misleading, since it can take care of both blocks and menus?

How can I import/export a menu that has a bunch of links inside it ? I want to export it from local to staging and prod. Features doesn't seem to work? I found menu Block and menu_import to say to be able to do that, but is there another easier or better way?

Answer (score 3):

My experience with Drupal 8 step by step

First of all, you need to install [Menu Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_export) module and activate it. After that, you will have Export Menu in the Structure part.

> **Steps to Export & Import**

1- In the Export Menu page `domain.com/admin/config/development/menu_export`, you have three option, at **Menu list** select which menus you want to export.

2- On the Export section, export your menus.

**(In this step menu setting will not be exported on YML file then you need to continue.)**

3- Now you need to export system configuration from `domain.com/admin/config/development/configuration/full/export` or `drush cex`

**Note: after export, you will have `menu_export.export_data.yml` file that contains your menu settings**

4- Transfer configuration anywhere you want, then you need to import them from `domain.com/admin/config/development/configuration/full/import` or `drush cim`

5- Then you need to import menus to your system from UI `domain.com/admin/config/development/menu_export/import`

> **Important Note**
>
> Clear your cache
>
> In some cases, mostly with **Administration** menu you need do and **extra step**. That you need to just open the edit Administration menu page and just saving it without any changes after this you should see your updated menu on administration as well.

Comment: Doesn't work for complex menus with multiple levels of nesting - the weights and parents configured through the UI are completely ignored upon import!

Answer (score 1):

Menus are made available as blocks. Thats's why they are available in the blocks admin area. Yes, Features does not export menu items themselves as that is content and their links might have different node id's to stage or production sites.

https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_import seems to be the best solution to me for the job. You could also see if https://www.drupal.org/project/uuid_features module will do the job, but not sur

Answer (score 0):

There are two modules for doing that:

1. There's also [Menu Import and Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_export):

> This module helps in exporting and importing Menu Items among
>   cloned sites which is not possible using CMI.
>
> This module exports the menu entity as config YAML and will be
>   imported on subsequent instances.

2. another one is [Config Menu Link](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link_config) module.

Answer (score 0):

If you need a one time export/import of your menus, here is a simple script to export/import menus, that you can re-use in `drush php` on a remote server (You can optionally export the menus content to some file in the `tmp` folder):

```
function menus_export() {
  $data = [];
  // The menus to export.
  $menus = ['footer-menu', 'main-menu'];
  foreach ($menus as $menu) {
    $menuLinkIds = \Drupal::entityQuery('menu_link_content')
      ->accessCheck(FALSE)
      ->condition('menu_name', $menu)
      ->execute();
    $menuLinks = \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::loadMultiple($menuLinkIds);
    foreach ($menuLinks as $link) {
      if (!empty($link)) {
        $linkArray = $link->toArray();
        foreach ($linkArray as $key => $linkArrayItem) {
          $linkData[$key] = reset($linkArrayItem);
        }
        $data[$menu][$link->id()] = $linkData;
        unset($linkData);
      }
    }
  }
  
  // You can optionally export the menus content to some file.
  file_put_contents( 'public://tmp/menu_export.txt', '<?php return '.var_export($data, true ).";\n" );

  return $data;
}
```

Afterwards import the menus:

```
function menus_import($data) {
  foreach ($data as $menu => $links) {
    foreach ($links as $link) {
      unset($link['id'], $link['revision_id']);
      $menuLinkEntity = \Drupal::entityQuery('menu_link_content')
        ->accessCheck(FALSE)
        ->condition('uuid', $link['uuid'])
        ->execute();
      if (!$menuLinkEntity) {
        $menuLinkEntity = \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::create();
      }
      else {
        $menuLinkEntity = \Drupal\menu_link_content\Entity\MenuLinkContent::load(reset($menuLinkEntity));
      }
      foreach ($link as $key => $items) {
        $menuLinkEntity->set($key, $items);
      }
      $menuLinkEntity->save();
    }
  }
}
```